# Generalised function equality

Tags: distribution-theory

Can you explain in which sense, for a generalized function
$$ Y^+(\phi):=\int_0^\infty e^{i\phi t}dt$$
we have
$(-i\phi)Y^+(\phi)=1$ ?

Here $\phi \in S^1$.

I clearly get that $\int_0^\infty e^{i\phi t}dt= \frac{1}{i\phi}\left.(e^{i\phi t})\right|_0^\infty$ and distribution means some nice behavior at infinity, but I'm kind of missig the details